# Помогите распарсить файл с помощью sed

Tags: html, linux, парсер, bash, sed

Помогите распарсить файл с помощью sed.
Есть файл file.txt с содержимым:

```
<img alt="Иван" src="/data/avatar/Avatara_11103_1627443673.jpg" style title="Иван" /> 
<button type="button" class="btn-main" data-popup="contact" data-email="ivan@example.com">Связаться</button>
<img alt="Пётр" src="/data/avatar/Avatara_13443_77.jpg" style title="Пётр" /> 
<button type="button" class="btn-main" data-popup="contact" data-email="petr@example.com">Связаться</button>
<img alt="Василий" src="/data/avatar/Avatara_6849_1635591169.gif" style title="Василий" /> 
<button type="button" class="btn-main" data-popup="contact" data-email="vasya@example.com">Связаться</button>
<img alt="Инна" src="/data/avatar/Avatara_55837_82.jpg" style title="Инна" /> 
<button type="button" class="btn-main" data-popup="contact" data-email="inna@example.com">Связаться</button>
<img alt="Ира" src="/data/avatar/Avatara_15749_751336644.jpg" style title="Ира" /> 
<button type="button" class="btn-main" data-popup="contact" data-email="ira@example.com">Связаться</button>
```

После обработки sed, хотел бы получить файл mail.txt

Иван              ivan@example.com
Пётр              petr@exampl.com
Василий     vasya@example.com
Инна             inna@example.com
Ира                ira@example.com

Пробовал несколько вариантов, пока получается криво-косо. Не хватает опыта работы с SED.

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454 . ru_RU: https://habr.com/ru/articles/175179/comments/#comment_6086921 . Вообще - попробуй чё-нить типа `miller` или `jc`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.